# Format places - java

Tags: java, for-loop, decimal

I need some help with rounding to equal places using a loop. I have some code which works but it is a very awkward method and I do not think it is good coding and really need some help with a for loop.

I have declared  above which I will parse into my main class.

I need some help implementing a for-loop to help tidy this code and remove all the "if" and "else if" statements, any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: do you want to **round** the values or do you want to **format** them?

Comment: format them depending on the user input. 1-10

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have two distinct cases:

1. When `noDecimal` is between 1 and 10.
2. When `noDecimal` is 0.

Thus, your code would need to look something like so:

```
double decimalPlace = noDecimal;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##########");

if (noDecimal == 0) {
    decimalPlace = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
}
else {
    decimalPlace = 1;
    StringBuilder formatString = new StringBuilder();
    formatString.append("#0.");
    for(int i = 0; i < noDecimal; i++) {
        formatString.append("0");
        decimalPlace /= 10;
    }       
    formatter = new DecimalFormat(formatString.toString());
}
```

For a `noDecimal` value of 2, this code would produce a `decimalPlace` value of `0.01` (1 -> 0.1 -> 0.01) and a formatter value of `#0.00`.

Comment: yes, after clearing that out that was the answer - i'm not fast enough to keep up with you =) but that's how it would work ^^

Comment: @MartinFrank: Yes the question title and content do not really match.